# Find frequency of words line by line in txt file Python (how to format properly)

Tags: python, list, file

I'm trying to make a simple program that can find the frequency of occurrences in a text file line by line. I have it outputting everything correctly except for when more than one word is on a line in the text file. (More information below)

The text file looks like this:

```
Hello
Hi
Hello
Good Day
Hi 
Good Day
Good Night
```

I want the output to be: (Doesn't have to be in the same order)

```
Hello: 2
Hi: 2
Good Day: 2
Good Night: 2
```

What it's currently outputting:

```
Day: 2
Good: 3
Hello: 2
Hi: 2
Night: 1
```

My code:

```
file = open("test.txt", "r") 
text = file.read() #reads file (I've tried .realine() & .readlines()


word_list = text.split(None)
word_freq = {}  # Declares empty dictionary

for word in word_list:
    word_freq[word] = word_freq.get(word, 0) + 1
    keys = sorted(word_freq.keys())

for word in keys:
    final=word.capitalize()
    print(final + ': ' + str(word_freq[word])) # Line that prints the output
```

Comment: How do you know that `Good day` is one word and not two? If you split your text based on white spaces then you'll consider this as 2 words...

Comment: That is what I'm asking about

Comment: Then don't split...

Comment: Then you should split your text based on `\n` character and not spaces...if your text always contains a `\n` character after each word....

Answer (score 1):

You want to preserve the lines. Don't split. Don't capitalize. Don't sort

Use a Counter

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter() 
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        c[line.rstrip()] += 1

for k, v in c.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```

Comment: Is there a way without modules?

Comment: Sure. But is that a requirement? You should update the question to say so

Comment: yes, how could I display my desired output as shown above

Comment: My answer already does that. Have you tried? Counter is part of the standard library. I'm not installing any modules

Comment: I mean I don't want to import anything. so without importing Counter

Comment: Your question didn't state that was a requirement. I'm just answering what you wanted. If that's your homework assignment, then you should edit the question to clarify that

Answer (score 0):

You can make it yourself very easy by using a Counter object. If you want to count the occurrences of full lines you can simply do:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('file.txt') as f:
    c = Counter(f)
print(c)
```

## Edit

Since you asked for a way without modules:

```
counter_dict = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    l = f.readlines()
    for line in l:
        if line not in counter_dict:
            counter_dict[line] = 0
        counter_dict[line] +=1
print(counter_dict)
```

Comment: What about no modules?

Comment: A file object is iterable. You shouldn't need readlines in the first example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the text by None, split it by each line break so you get each line into a list.

```
file = open("test.txt", "r") 
text = file.read() #reads file (I've tried .realine() & .readlines()

word_list = text.split('\n')
word_freq = {}  # Declares empty dictionary

for word in word_list:
    word_freq[word] = word_freq.get(word, 0) + 1
    keys = sorted(word_freq.keys())

for word in keys:
    final=word.capitalize()
    print(final + ': ' + str(word_freq[word])) # Line that prints the output
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers, most of the code produces the desired output just in different ways. The code I ended up using with no modules was this:

```
file = open("test.txt", "r") 
text = file.read() #reads file (I've tried .realine() & .readlines()

word_list = text.split('\n')
word_freq = {}  # Declares empty dictionary

for word in word_list:
    word_freq[word] = word_freq.get(word, 0) + 1
    keys = sorted(word_freq.keys())

for word in keys:
    final=word.capitalize()
    print(final + ': ' + str(word_freq[word])) # Line that prints the output
```

The code I ended up using with modules was this:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter() 
with open('live.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        c[line.rstrip()] += 1

for k, v in c.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```